# Best practice for accessing global Silverlight application data

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I've got a bunch of Silverlight 5 applications hosted in a website that set some application specific data. One of these datum is a CurrentUser object.

On startup of the app (each one), it talks to a web service to pull in the current user information. However, this needs to be accessed from all sorts of places in the SL application.

I thought it made sense to put it on the Application object itself, but I wasn't sure if this was a good practice.

I put a simple property containing the user in an interface and implemented it on the main application class.

Then, the rest of the application code accesses it via a static class:

```
Public Module ApplicationUtils

    Public Property CurrentUser() As ConnectEntities.WebUser
        Get
            Dim app As ICommonAppData = TryCast(Application.Current, ICommonAppData)
            If (app IsNot Nothing) Then
                Return app.CurrentUser
            End If
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value As ConnectEntities.WebUser)
            Dim app As ICommonAppData = TryCast(Application.Current, ICommonAppData)
            If (app IsNot Nothing) Then
                app.CurrentUser = value
            End If

            Throw New NotImplementedException("Current application does not implement required interface")
        End Set
    End Property

End Module
```

I'm not terribly familiar with Silverlight, so I'm trying to find out if this is an accepted practice to access global data, or if there is a complication I'm not realizing here (thread safety issues, etc.).

Comment: @ chris for `Application.Current` to work you need to work in elevated privileges for SL.

Comment: @user2526236, interesting. Way out of my depth of knowledge now. Googling around indicates we need a signed XAP and a registry setting. Signing a xap is easy enough, but how does one set a registry setting on someone else's computer from a SL5 app, if at all? Also, how do I tell if perhaps it is already running trusted? (it is a legacy app) I believe checking the checkbox on project properties only enables it for local testing.

Comment: @ chris Pls refer to this MSDN doc. we were having a exe for clients to install for changing the reg value ..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @user2526236 thanks, I'll take a look at that, but I don't think a separate exe is an option. Circling back to the original question, is this really the right way to access/store this information in Silverlight, or is there a more appropriate and simpler way to handle it?

Comment: @user2526236 where is it mentioned that I need to have elevated permissions to use Application.Current? I can see a bunch of places in this existing app I have that accesses Application.Current properties like Resources and RootVisual, but I don't believe it has elevated permissions. Just trying to find the definitive word on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find anywhere that mentioned any details on needing elevated privileges to access the Application.Current property. As well, in all of my testing, it appears that I am able to access this property as desired without having to have elevated privileges (both local testing as well as with the app deployed on other machines).

I have moved ahead with my original design and everything seems to work fine.

Whether it is a best practice or not, I don't know. However, it seems a reasonably clean solution to accessing this type of data.